# Loop a script based on multiple rows in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script

I am teacher who is trying to make a routine documentation faster for our staff. I have created a google sheet that will embed information from the cell row onto a google doc. I would like to figure out a way that when I run the script it will run it for each row and collect all of it onto a pdf so I print data from multiple students all at once.

Any ideas on how I could make this work? The script I currently have is below and it works for one row.

```
//Create the Menu

function onOpen() {
var menuEntries = [ {name: "ALE", functionName: "CreatePDF"}];
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
ss.addMenu("Generate my Monthly Narrative", menuEntries);
}

function CreatePDF() {
var sleepINT = 500;
var templateid = "10rmEYtoWlDd1z0QLh9GcBn7d0CKH-7m6sE9FmKSXEuI";
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
ss.toast("YOU LOVE ALE...YOU LOVE ALE... YOU LOVE ALE");
Utilities.sleep(sleepINT);
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var data = sheet.getRange(4,1,sheet.getLastRow()-1, 
sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
//    var data = sheet.getRange(4,1,1,sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
//var month = sheet.getRange(4,1,1,111).getValues();
//  var month = sheet.getRange(4,5).getValues();
ss.toast("Thank you. Your ALE is processing!");
Utilities.sleep(sleepINT);


for (var i in data) {
var row = data[i];
// setting up the temporary document
var docid = DriveApp.getFileById(templateid).makeCopy().getId();
var doc = DocumentApp.openById(docid);
var body = doc.getBody();

// setting the variables to use in the document
var boxChecked = "☑";
var boxEmpty = "☐";
var studentName = row[0];
var emailAddress = row[1];
var grade = row[2];
var trimester = row[3];
var month = row[4];
var time = row[5];
var weekEnded1 = Utilities.formatDate(row[6], "PDT", 'MM/dd/YYYY');
var todayDate1 = Utilities.formatDate(row[7], "PDT", 'MM/dd/YYYY');
var face1; if ( row[8] === true ) { face1 = boxChecked } else { face1 = boxEmpty }; 
var phone1; if ( row[9] === true ) { phone1 = boxChecked } else { phone1 = boxEmpty }; 
var interElectronic1; if ( row[10] === true ) { interElectronic1 = boxChecked } else { interElectronic1 = boxEmpty }; 
var notAble1; if ( row[11] === true ) { notAble1 = boxChecked } else { notAble1 = boxEmpty }; 
var attendedClass1; if ( row[12] === true ) { attendedClass1 = boxChecked } else { attendedClass1 = boxEmpty };
var testing1; if ( row[13] === true ) { testing1 = boxChecked } else { testing1 = boxEmpty };
var instruction1; if ( row[14] === true ) { instruction1 = boxChecked } else { instruction1 = boxEmpty };
var learningActivity1; if ( row[15] === true ) { learningActivity1 = boxChecked } else { learningActivity1 = boxEmpty };
var reviewAssignments1; if ( row[16] === true ) { reviewAssignments1 = boxChecked } else { reviewAssignments1 = boxEmpty };
var reportingprogress1; if ( row[17] === true ) { reportingprogress1 = boxChecked } else { reportingprogress1 = boxEmpty };
var status1 = row[18];
var comment1 = row[19];
var weekEnded2 = Utilities.formatDate(row[20], "PDT", 'MM/dd/YYYY');
var todayDate2 = Utilities.formatDate(row[21], "PDT", 'MM/dd/YYYY');
var face2; if ( row[22] === true ) { face2 = boxChecked } else { face2 = boxEmpty }; 
var phone2; if ( row[23] === true ) { phone2 = boxChecked } else { phone2 = boxEmpty }; 
var interElectronic2; if ( row[24] === true ) { interElectronic2 = boxChecked } else { interElectronic2 = boxEmpty }; 
var notAble2; if ( row[25] === true ) { notAble2 = boxChecked } else { notAble2 = boxEmpty }; 
var attendedClass2; if ( row[26] === true ) { attendedClass2 = boxChecked } else { attendedClass2 = boxEmpty };
var testing2; if ( row[27] === true ) { testing2 = boxChecked } else { testing2 = boxEmpty };
var instruction2; if ( row[28] === true ) { instruction2 = boxChecked } else { instruction2 = boxEmpty };
var learningActivity2; if ( row[29] === true ) { learningActivity2 = boxChecked } else { learningActivity2 = boxEmpty };
var reviewAssignments2; if ( row[30] === true ) { reviewAssignments2 = boxChecked } else { reviewAssignments2 = boxEmpty };
var reportingprogress2; if ( row[31] === true ) { reportingprogress2 = boxChecked } else { reportingprogress2 = boxEmpty };
var status2 = row[32];
var comment2 = row[33];
var weekEnded3 = Utilities.formatDate(row[34], "PDT", 'MM/dd/YYYY');
var todayDate3 = Utilities.formatDate(row[35], "PDT", 'MM/dd/YYYY');
var face3; if ( row[36] === true ) { face3 = boxChecked } else { face3 = boxEmpty }; 
var phone3; if ( row[37] === true ) { phone3 = boxChecked } else { phone3 = boxEmpty }; 
var interElectronic3; if ( row[38] === true ) { interElectronic3 = boxChecked } else { interElectronic3 = boxEmpty }; 
var notAble3; if ( row[39] === true ) { notAble3 = boxChecked } else { notAble3 = boxEmpty }; 
var attendedClass3; if ( row[40] === true ) { attendedClass3 = boxChecked } else { attendedClass3 = boxEmpty };
var testing3; if ( row[41] === true ) { testing3 = boxChecked } else { testing3 = boxEmpty };
var instruction3; if ( row[42] === true ) { instruction3 = boxChecked } else { instruction3 = boxEmpty };
var learningActivity3; if ( row[43] === true ) { learningActivity3 = boxChecked } else { learningActivity3 = boxEmpty };
var reviewAssignments3; if ( row[44] === true ) { reviewAssignments3 = boxChecked } else { reviewAssignments3 = boxEmpty };
var reportingprogress3; if ( row[45] === true ) { reportingprogress3 = boxChecked } else { reportingprogress3 = boxEmpty };
var status3 = row[46];
var comment3 = row[47];
var weekEnded4 = Utilities.formatDate(row[48], "PDT", 'MM/dd/YYYY');
var todayDate4 = Utilities.formatDate(row[49], "PDT", 'MM/dd/YYYY');
var face4; if ( row[50] === true ) { face4 = boxChecked } else { face4 = boxEmpty }; 
var phone4; if ( row[51] === true ) { phone4 = boxChecked } else { phone4 = boxEmpty }; 
var interElectronic4; if ( row[52] === true ) { interElectronic4 = boxChecked } else { interElectronic4 = boxEmpty }; 
var notAble4; if ( row[53] === true ) { notAble4 = boxChecked } else { notAble4 = boxEmpty }; 
var attendedClass4; if ( row[54] === true ) { attendedClass4 = boxChecked } else { attendedClass4 = boxEmpty };
var testing4; if ( row[55] === true ) { testing4 = boxChecked } else { testing4 = boxEmpty };
var instruction4; if ( row[56] === true ) { instruction4 = boxChecked } else { instruction4 = boxEmpty };
var learningActivity4; if ( row[57] === true ) { learningActivity4 = boxChecked } else { learningActivity4 = boxEmpty };
var reviewAssignments4; if ( row[58] === true ) { reviewAssignments4 = boxChecked } else { reviewAssignments4 = boxEmpty };
var reportingprogress4; if ( row[59] === true ) { reportingprogress4 = boxChecked } else { reportingprogress4 = boxEmpty };
var status4 = row[60];
var comment4 = row[61];
var weekEnded5 = Utilities.formatDate(row[62], "PDT", 'MM/dd/YYYY');
var todayDate5 = Utilities.formatDate(row[63], "PDT", 'MM/dd/YYYY');
var face5; if ( row[64] === true ) { face5 = boxChecked } else { face5 = boxEmpty }; 
var phone5; if ( row[65] === true ) { phone5 = boxChecked } else { phone5 = boxEmpty }; 
var interElectronic5; if ( row[66] === true ) { interElectronic5 = boxChecked } else { interElectronic5 = boxEmpty }; 
var notAble5; if ( row[67] === true ) { notAble5 = boxChecked } else { notAble5 = boxEmpty }; 
var attendedClass5; if ( row[68] === true ) { attendedClass5 = boxChecked } else { attendedClass5 = boxEmpty };
var testing5; if ( row[69] === true ) { testing5 = boxChecked } else { testing5 = boxEmpty };
var instruction5; if ( row[70] === true ) { instruction5 = boxChecked } else { instruction5 = boxEmpty };
var learningActivity5; if ( row[71] === true ) { learningActivity5 = boxChecked } else { learningActivity5 = boxEmpty };
var reviewAssignments5; if ( row[72] === true ) { reviewAssignments5 = boxChecked } else { reviewAssignments5 = boxEmpty };
var reportingprogress5; if ( row[73] === true ) { reportingprogress5 = boxChecked } else { reportingprogress5 = boxEmpty };
var status5 = row[74];
var comment5 = row[75];
var date = Utilities.formatDate(row[76], "PDT", 'MM/dd/YYYY');
var className1 = row[77]
var percent1; if (row[78] === "" ) {percent1 = ""} else {percent1 = row[78] * 100 + "%"};
var grade1 = row[79];
var missing1 = row[80];
var content1 = row[81];
var className2 = row[82]
var percent2; if (row[83] === "" ) {percent2 = ""} else {percent2 = row[83] * 100 + "%"};
var grade2 = row[84];
var missing2 = row[85];
var content2 = row[86];
var className3 = row[87]
var percent3; if (row[88] === "" ) {percent3 = ""} else {percent3 = row[88] * 100 + "%"};
var grade3 = row[89];
var missing3 = row[90];
var content3 = row[91];
var className4 = row[92]
var percent4; if (row[93] === "" ) {percent4 = ""} else {percent4 = row[93] * 100 + "%"};
var grade4 = row[94];
var missing4 = row[95];
var content4 = row[96];
var className5 = row[97]
var percent5; if (row[98] === "" ) {percent5 = ""} else {percent5 = row[98] * 100 + "%"};
var grade5 = row[99];
var missing5 = row[100];
var content5 = row[101];
var className6 = row[102]
var percent6; if (row[103] === "" ) {percent6 = ""} else {percent6 = row[103] * 100 + "%"};
var grade6 = row[104];
var missing6 = row[105];
var content6 = row[106];
var attendance = row[107];
var behavior = row[108];
var comments = row[109];
var overall = row[110];

body.replaceText('keystudentname', studentName);
body.replaceText("keygradelevel", grade);
body.replaceText("keytrimester", trimester);
body.replaceText("keymonth", month);
body.replaceText("keytime", time);
body.replaceText("keyweekend1", weekEnded1);
body.replaceText("keytodaydate1", todayDate1);
body.replaceText("keyf1", face1);
body.replaceText("keyp1", phone1);
body.replaceText("keyie1", interElectronic1);
body.replaceText("keyna1", notAble1);
body.replaceText("keyac1", attendedClass1);
body.replaceText("keyt1", testing1);
body.replaceText("keyi1", instruction1);
body.replaceText("keyla1", learningActivity1);
body.replaceText("keyra1", reviewAssignments1);
body.replaceText("keyrp1", reportingprogress1);
body.replaceText("keystatus1", status1);
body.replaceText("keycomment1", comment1);
body.replaceText("keyweekend2", weekEnded2);
body.replaceText("keytodaydate2", todayDate2);
body.replaceText("keyf2", face2);
body.replaceText("keyp2", phone2);
body.replaceText("keyie2", interElectronic2);
body.replaceText("keyna2", notAble2);
body.replaceText("keyac2", attendedClass2);
body.replaceText("keyt2", testing2);
body.replaceText("keyi2", instruction2);
body.replaceText("keyla2", learningActivity2);
body.replaceText("keyra2", reviewAssignments2);
body.replaceText("keyrp2", reportingprogress2);
body.replaceText("keystatus2", status2);
body.replaceText("keycomment2", comment2);    
body.replaceText("keyweekend3", weekEnded3);
body.replaceText("keytodaydate3", todayDate3);
body.replaceText("keyf3", face3);
body.replaceText("keyp3", phone3);
body.replaceText("keyie3", interElectronic3);
body.replaceText("keyna3", notAble3);
body.replaceText("keyac3", attendedClass3);
body.replaceText("keyt3", testing3);
body.replaceText("keyi3", instruction3);
body.replaceText("keyla3", learningActivity3);
body.replaceText("keyra3", reviewAssignments3);
body.replaceText("keyrp3", reportingprogress3);
body.replaceText("keystatus3", status3);
body.replaceText("keycomment3", comment3);
body.replaceText("keyweekend4", weekEnded4);
body.replaceText("keytodaydate4", todayDate4);
body.replaceText("keyf4", face4);
body.replaceText("keyp4", phone4);
body.replaceText("keyie4", interElectronic4);
body.replaceText("keyna4", notAble4);
body.replaceText("keyac4", attendedClass4);
body.replaceText("keyt4", testing4);
body.replaceText("keyi4", instruction4);
body.replaceText("keyla4", learningActivity4);
body.replaceText("keyra4", reviewAssignments4);
body.replaceText("keyrp4", reportingprogress4);
body.replaceText("keystatus4", status4);
body.replaceText("keycomment4", comment4);     
body.replaceText("keyweekend5", weekEnded5);
body.replaceText("keytodaydate5", todayDate5);
body.replaceText("keyf5", face5);
body.replaceText("keyp5", phone5);
body.replaceText("keyie5", interElectronic5);
body.replaceText("keyna5", notAble5);
body.replaceText("keyac5", attendedClass5);
body.replaceText("keyt5", testing5);
body.replaceText("keyi5", instruction5);
body.replaceText("keyla5", learningActivity5);
body.replaceText("keyra5", reviewAssignments5);
body.replaceText("keyrp5", reportingprogress5);
body.replaceText("keystatus5", status5);
body.replaceText("keycomment5", comment5);    
body.replaceText("keydate", date);
body.replaceText("keyclass1", className1);
body.replaceText("keypercent1", percent1);
body.replaceText("keygrade1", grade1);
body.replaceText("keymissing1", missing1);
body.replaceText("keycontent1", content1);
body.replaceText("keyclass2", className2);
body.replaceText("keypercent2", percent2);
body.replaceText("keygrade2", grade2);
body.replaceText("keymissing2", missing2);
body.replaceText("keycontent2", content2);
body.replaceText("keyclass3", className3); 
body.replaceText("keypercent3", percent3);
body.replaceText("keygrade3", grade3);
body.replaceText("keymissing3", missing3);
body.replaceText("keycontent3", content3);
body.replaceText("keyclass4", className4);
body.replaceText("keypercent4", percent4);
body.replaceText("keygrade4", grade4);
body.replaceText("keymissing4", missing4);
body.replaceText("keycontent4", content4);
body.replaceText("keyclass5", className5); 
body.replaceText("keypercent5", percent5);
body.replaceText("keygrade5", grade5);
body.replaceText("keymissing5", missing5);
body.replaceText("keycontent5", content5);
body.replaceText("keyclass6", className6); 
body.replaceText("keypercent6", percent6);
body.replaceText("keygrade6", grade6);
body.replaceText("keymissing6", missing6);
body.replaceText("keycontent6", content6);
body.replaceText("keyattendance", attendance);
body.replaceText("keybehavior", behavior);
body.replaceText("keycomments", comments);
body.replaceText("keyoverall", overall);

ss.toast("Creating your ALE document");
Utilities.sleep(sleepINT);


var file = DriveApp.getFileById(doc.getId());
var newfolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1oQ8evDj8dlHoDdX01DvZqjcIkSq31oen");
var oldfolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1IzY9PiobBC-O87AxCkU32j2n2wUU1zUE");
newfolder.addFile(file);
oldfolder.removeFile(file);

ss.toast("PDF has been created!");
Utilities.sleep(sleepINT);

var usernamefordoctitle = sheet.getRange(4,1,1,1).getValues()
var name = doc.getName();
doc.setName(month + " ALE for " + studentName);
ss.toast("Document has been named");
Utilities.sleep(sleepINT);

doc.saveAndClose();
var pdffolder = DriveApp.getFolderById ("1iwBEUZpFwz_eaCVKemYozF5FA0_t0YGv");
var pdfFILE = DriveApp.getFileById(doc.getId()).getAs('application/pdf');
pdfFILE.setName(doc.getName() + ".pdf");
var theFile = DriveApp.createFile(pdfFILE);
pdffolder.addFile(theFile);
ss.toast("Document has been saved to Google Drive");
Utilities.sleep(sleepINT);

var pdfEMAIL = 
DriveApp.getFileById(doc.getId()).getAs('application/pdf').getBytes();
var message = "This is your" + month + "ALE documents for your AG student."
var emailTo = emailAddress;
var subject = "Your " + month + " ALE for " + studentName + " ";
var message = "The attached pdf document is your " + month + " monthly ALE document for " + studentName + ".";

MailApp.sendEmail(emailTo, subject, message, {attachments: pdfFILE});
ss.toast("Email has been sent");
Utilities.sleep(sleepINT);
ss.toast(" FINISHED!!!! ");
}}
```

Comment: It only loops once?  How long does it take to complete the code.  You can click the "View" menu and choose Execution Transcript and see if there is an error, and how long it took for the code to run.  I don't think your problem is this line `for (var i in data) {` but I would use: `for (var i = 0; i < data.length ; i++) {`

Comment: It takes about 23.5 seconds to complete the script. The problem is not that it won't run the script. It runs it just fine. The thing that I am trying to do is make the script run for each row of the sheets to create a pdf for each row. Ideally, I would like it if each row combined into one pdf so I got one email with one pdf for each student that I record documentation for. I hope that makes sense :-)

Comment: The way that the code is set up, it looks like it would already loop through every row in the sheet.  Do you see the final toast message?  `ss.toast(" FINISHED!!!! ");` And then it doesn't run again?

Comment: Correct. It doesn't continue to another row.

Comment: There is only one thing that causes the loop: `for (var i in data) {`  There is no `break;` statement to cause the loop to stop.  If there is no error, then an error is not causing the loop to stop.  So, the only thing left that can cause the loop to not work is `for (var i in data) {`

Comment: I have a whole spreadsheet filled out but it still won't send multiple emails. Thank you so much for your help Sandy!